# Change WinForms Button Style upon mousedown and leave

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I change a button's style, in particular the image, upon the mouse being pressed and held and then the cursor dragged away from the button?

You'll notice that, on this action, the default behaviour for the button is to revert it's style to hover style. This can be partially configured using the MouseOverBackColor. I want to ensure that, whenever the MouseOverBackColor is applied, I also have a specific image on the button.

I have tried the code below, to have an "isMouseDown" flag which is checked in the leave event. However, this doesn't work for me.

```
    private void btnFormMinimize_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
    }

    bool isMouseDown = false;
    private void btnFormMinimize_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = (Button)sender;
        b.Image = Properties.Resources.icon_minimize_click;

        isMouseDown = true;
    }

    private void btnFormMinimize_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = (Button)sender;
        b.Image = Properties.Resources.icon_minimize_hover;
    }

    private void btnFormMinimize_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button b = (Button)sender;

        if (isMouseDown)
        {
            b.Image = Properties.Resources.icon_minimize_hover;
        }
        else
        {
            b.Image = Properties.Resources.icon_minimize;
        }
    }

    private void btnFormMinimize_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        isMouseDown= false;
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what shall happen when the user releases the button after he has left the button?

Comment: The button will return to it's normal state and style, i.e. not clicked and not hovered over.